# No matching version found for browserslist@^4.19.1

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm getting this message when I try to run create-react-app.
This happens both within the VSC terminal and on Command Prompt. I hadn't changed any settings on my pc.

Then got the message below, and the troubleshooting I've tried so far is un- and re-installing Node, create-react-app and VSC.

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\user1\test.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for your browserslist@^4.19.1.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist. 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found at (**file location**)

Aborting installation.
  npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting text/ from C:\Users\user1
Done.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this command

```
npm cache clean --force
```